# Castle Windsor advanced factory registration

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

having the class:

```
public class SomeClass{
     public SomeClass(IBlabla bla, string name){
         //....
     }
}
```

I can write factory:

```
public class SomeClassFactory{
public SomeClassFactory(IBlabla bla){
         //....
     }
    public SomeClass Create(string name){return new SomeClass(_bla, name)}
}
```

And live with it. But I wonder, is there any solution to do this without such obvious factory implementation, in the same way as .AsFactory() works, but with additional parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely possible, and you can even do it without an implementation through the [typed factories](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) in Castle. Here is how :

Given your base classes:

```
public interface IBlabla
{
}

public class Blabla : IBlabla
{
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IBlabla Blabla { get; set; }
    public SomeClass(IBlabla bla, string named)
    {
        Blabla = bla;
        Name = named;
    }
}
```

you can create a generic factory for elements with a `string named` in their constructor:

```
public interface IFactory
{
    T Build<T>(string named);
}
```

No need for any implementation, you are going to use a tool that will create an automatic implementation of your factory backed up by Castle:

```
// container
var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer(); 
// factory facility, needed to add behavior
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>(); 
// let's register what we need
container.Register(
        // your factory interface
        Component.For<IFactory>().AsFactory(),
        // your IBlabla
        Component.For<IBlabla>().ImplementedBy<Blabla>(),
        // component, you could register against an interface
        Component.For<SomeClass>().ImplementedBy<SomeClass>()
    );
// shazam, let's build our SomeClass
var result = container.Resolve<IFactory>().Build<SomeClass>("bla?");
```

Why does it work? When going through a typed factory, Castle will try and hand the object being resolved all the parameters that are passed to the factory call. So the `named` parameter is given to the constructor of your `SomeClass`. The `IBlabla` is resolved through standard behavior for Castle.

There you are, factory without any implementation are neat :D

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful, but need having couple of tests have to add that names in constructor and create methods should be exactly the same, coz in other situation - it would fail.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but you can either test the factory by comparing the passed parameter and the resulting object's name, or you could lean on the castle tests themselves, which you should find here: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/tree/master/src/Castle.Windsor.Tests/Facilities/TypedFactory

Comment: I meant that if in ctor u insert string someName, then in Build u should have exactly "someName", not "name", or "param1". I've tested. that was my mistake. Many thanks for working example, that have helped very much.