# Auto factory method for Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, factory

Okay, i'm new in Ninject, but i'm quite familiar with Windsor.

With Windsor i can create factory for class just using interface and use AsFactory method.

For example like answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574784/castle-windsor-advanced-factory-registration) question.

So here is fair question: how to do the same with Ninject?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Ninject.Extensions.Factory` package to accomplish this: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory